# How to get plurality of noun?

Tags: java, ruby

In Ruby on Rails, this is plural and singular functions added to Ruby string class.

How can I implements plural and singular functions in Java?

Example:

```
"book"  plural() => "books"
"books"  singular  =>  "book"
```

Comment: This is a dupe of an earlier question... that I'm having trouble finding. It was about 2 weeks ago. If you find the question, you'll also have the answer! :)

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment rather than an answer, because I've never tried to do anything like this, but Rails runs under JRuby, and you can compile JRuby into .class files, so what if you compiled the Rails Inflector class (or as much of ActiveSupport as necessary) into Java, then just included it from the Java?

Comment: @Carl - [this is the earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189432/effective-way-to-handle-singular-plural-word-based-on-some-collection-size), but it's not a duplicate, that one asked for a solution in Java only (Carl, you even commented the best answer given there ;) )

Comment: @Andreas_D: That's why I remembered it. But... this question is asking about Java (only) too, isn't it? So technically a dupe, though I wouldn't fault the poster for it. Or am I all mixed up?

Comment: @Carl - oh yes, ruby is only mentioned in the first line. As a reference... It is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to cover the exception cases too (e.g. person => people) then the module that handles this in Ruby on Rails is called `Inflector`. Take a look at this [Inflector](https://inflector.dev.java.net/) project on java.net for something similar in Java. From the project summary:

> Inflector is a Java API for forming
>   plurals of words. The library supports
>   English spellings, and is locale-aware
>   so it is straightforward to customize
>   for any language.

Note: that I think this might only do singular => plural and not the other way around.

Comment: If I remember correctly, that was the best answer given to the previous question I mentioned. +1. :)

Comment: Thank you 
It is very nice of you 

I get another method
the url is  
http://www.oschina.net/bbs/thread/104

be concerned with the code only

i hope you can understand Chinese
haha