# Java - Pluralization package?

Tags: java, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plural form of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907296/plural-form-of-a-word)

Is there some existing class or library for adding "s" to a String if I pass it a number that's not 1? Basically, I have a cat. If I have 1 cat, I need the String "cat". If I have 2 cats, I need the String "cats". It's a simple thing to do myself, but after I did it, I thought there's probably already a library I could import for it. However, as you can see, I am having difficulty putting this into words to Google a name for the package, if it exists. :P It's just that I write this function all the time, I'm wondering if it exists already.

Comment: You want an API that pluralizes?

Comment: @JonLin yeah, pretty much. XD Is there a pluralizing package for Java? Really I'm doing just time words (seconds, minutes, hours), but if there's one for cacti too, that'd be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pluralizing is probably simple enough, with the exception of the list of [words like "cactus" or "tooth"](http://www.hintsandthings.co.uk/library/plurals.htm) that are somewhat special cases, that you don't need an entire API or you can implement yourself. If you really don't want to have a stab at it, there are things like the [`Inflector` library](http://www.atteo.org/2011/12/12/Evo-Inflector.html) that can do it for you. There are probably others, if you search for "java pluralize".

Javadocs for Inflector here: http://www.atteo.org/static/evo-inflector/apidocs/index.html

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why my idiot brain decided to forget the word pluralize! ...

Answer (score 0):

> Really I'm doing just time words (seconds, minutes, hours) ...

If you have a small / fixed set of words, it is probably simpler to use a static lookup table or something like that.  A general solution is too heavy-weight, IMO.

Comment: True. I'll probably find a better package for my other projects so I can stop having output like "tooths", where I wasn't paying attention. For the small set of words, I'll continue using a simple function.